# Does the Ender 3 need an 8 pin mini USB or 5 pin, or no difference?

Tags: creality-ender-3

I've been searching for a reassuring answer for a week now. What type of mini USB does the Creality Ender 3 need? I have studied about them and five pin seems to be the answer but I haven't found a reassuring answer.

If anyone knows the answer would you please inform me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ender 3 follows the USB standard for a [USB-2.0/2.0 revised 5 pin USB-Mini-B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Receptacle_(socket)_identification).

To prove, a picture of it. Left, you can clearly count the 5 pins that conform to the standard.

[image: Ender-3 front]

as a side note: There is no 8 pin USB-Mini - Mini has the T-shape. In fact, there is not even a USB standard conform plug that has 8-pins! The standard allows only 4, 5, 9, 11 and 24 pins

Comment: At any rate, USB standards (except for USB-C) are hardware backward compatible. Even if the Ender 3 had a connector with >5 pins, as long as it is USB, the smaller connector would still work.

Comment: yes @ifconfig but there is no 8-pin USB Mini that fits into that socket.

Comment: @Trish thanks! You answered several of my questions in one go! And thanks for taking the time to add the picture. It both helped and added to my knowledge! Kudos!

Comment: @ifconfig thank you very much for the extra info. That is one good piece of information! Kudos!